# Multiple Lines in Google Charts from MySQL Array

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I am trying to pass off my MySQL query into a Google Line chart but having some issues getting it into the right format.
The chart is to show a percentage of RAM utilisation on a computer.

MySQL Query:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(date, 'new Date(%Y, %c, %d, %H, %i, %s)') AS date, percentComittedInUse, machineName FROM stsdata.hyperv_perf_memory
```

Table Results (Shortened):

```
+-----------------------------------+----------------------+-------------+
|               date                | percentComittedInUse | machineName |
+-----------------------------------+----------------------+-------------+
| new Date(2018, 8, 17, 17, 09, 03) |                   53 | STSWKS15    |
| new Date(2018, 8, 17, 17, 32, 43) |                   57 | STSWKS15    |
| new Date(2018, 8, 17, 18, 02, 53) |                   55 | STSWKS15    |
| new Date(2018, 8, 17, 18, 33, 00) |                   56 | STSWKS15    |
| new Date(2018, 8, 17, 19, 03, 05) |                   57 | STSWKS15    |
| new Date(2018, 8, 20, 14, 02, 30) |                   57 | STSWKS15    |
| new Date(2018, 8, 20, 14, 32, 46) |                   57 | STSWKS15    |
| new Date(2018, 8, 20, 15, 02, 56) |                   59 | STSWKS15    |
| new Date(2018, 8, 20, 15, 33, 08) |                   60 | STSWKS15    |
| new Date(2018, 8, 17, 17, 32, 43) |                   50 | FAKE_VHOST8 |
| new Date(2018, 8, 17, 18, 02, 53) |                   48 | FAKE_VHOST8 |
| new Date(2018, 8, 17, 18, 33, 00) |                   49 | FAKE_VHOST8 |
| new Date(2018, 8, 17, 19, 03, 05) |                   50 | FAKE_VHOST8 |
| new Date(2018, 8, 17, 19, 33, 27) |                   49 | FAKE_VHOST8 |
| new Date(2018, 8, 17, 20, 02, 33) |                   49 | FAKE_VHOST8 |
| new Date(2018, 8, 17, 20, 32, 41) |                   50 | FAKE_VHOST8 |
+-----------------------------------+----------------------+-------------+
```

I am echoing in the results using PHP:

```
<?php
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($VMMemoryPerf);
if ($VMMemoryPerf->num_rows > 0) {
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($VMMemoryPerf)) {
        echo "[".$row['date'].", '".$row['machineName']."', '".$row['percentComittedInUse']."'],";
        }
    }
?>
```

The results work as expected, it will return:
`[new Date(2018, 8, 17, 17, 32, 43), 'STSWKS15', '57'], [new Date(2018, 8, 17, 18, 02, 53), 'STSWKS15', '55'],`

But I have multiple computer names and want a line in the graph for each.

I was exploring a way to manipulate the data in MySQL but if I have to do so in PHP that is OK too.

Javascript for the Chart:

```js
<?php include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']. "/inc/SQL_stsdata.php"); ?>
<script type="text/javascript">
 google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
 google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(chart_line_hyperv_memory);
 function chart_line_hyperv_memory() {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
   [{ label: 'Date', type: 'datetime' }, { role: 'annotationText' }, { label: 'Memory % Comitted', type: 'number' }],
   <?php
   $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($VMMemoryPerf);
   if ($VMMemoryPerf->num_rows > 0) {
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($VMMemoryPerf)) {
     echo "[".$row['date'].", '".$row['machineName']."', '".$row['percentComittedInUse']."'],";
    }
   }
   ?>
   ]);
  var options = {
   title: 'VM Memory Utilization', fontSize: 10, fontName: 'Consolas',
   tooltip: { textStyle: { bold: false, color: '#000000', fontSize: 12 }, showColorCode: true, isHtml: true, ignoreBounds: false, text: 'both', trigger: 'hover', padding: '0px' },
   animation: { duration: 1000, startup: true, easing: 'inAndOut' },
   legend: { position: 'right' },
   chartArea: { height: '95%' },
   width: '100%', height: '100%',
   annotations: { textStyle: { fontName: 'Consolas', color: '#000000', }, highContrast: 'true', alwaysOutside: 'true', },
  };
  var chart = document.getElementById('chart_line_hyperv_memory'), x = (parseFloat(chart.getAttribute('data-x')) || 0), y = (parseFloat(chart.getAttribute('data-y')) || 0);
  var chartContainer = $(chart).parent();
  chart.style.width  = chartContainer.width() + 'px';
  chart.style.height = chartContainer.height() + 'px';
  x += chartContainer.left;
  y += chartContainer.top;
  chart.style.webkitTransform = chart.style.transform = 'translate(' + x + 'px,' + y + 'px)';
  chart.setAttribute('data-x', x);
  chart.setAttribute('data-y', y);
  var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_line_hyperv_memory'));
  console.log(data);
  chart.draw(data, options);

 }
</script>
```

Thanks for reviewing and any help thrown my way!

**Update:**
The chart expects a table output such as:

```
+-------------------------------------+----------+-------------+
|                date                 | STSWKS15 | FAKE_VHOST8 |
+-------------------------------------+----------+-------------+
| Date(year, date, day, hour, minute) | value    | value       |
| Date(year, date, day, hour, minute) | value    | value       |
| Date(year, date, day, hour, minute) | value    | value       |
| Date(year, date, day, hour, minute) | value    | value       |
| Date(year, date, day, hour, minute) | value    | value       |
+-------------------------------------+----------+-------------+
```

So it can construct the data such as `[Date(), value, value],`
I have no issue with the concatenation in MySQL, just the query to flip the results per machine into their own columns.

Keeping in mind that if a new machine is added into the table the query can pick it up dynamically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the expected output you have added in the update, I think you are basically looking for a pivot table.

```
SELECT 
    DATE_FORMAT(date, 'new Date(%Y, %c, %d, %H, %i, %s)') AS date,
    SUM(IF(machineName = 'STSWKS15', percentComittedInUse, 0)) AS 'STSWKS15',
    SUM(IF(machineName = 'FAKE_VHOST8', percentComittedInUse, 0)) AS 'FAKE_VHOST8'
FROM stsdata.hyperv_perf_memory
GROUP BY `date`;
```

This would return something like this:

```
date                              |STSWKS15 |FAKE_VHOST8 |
----------------------------------|---------|------------|
new Date(2018, 8, 21, 10, 53, 27) |15       |0           |
new Date(2018, 8, 21, 10, 53, 44) |25       |0           |
new Date(2018, 8, 21, 10, 53, 57) |57       |0           |
new Date(2018, 8, 21, 10, 54, 13) |60       |0           |
new Date(2018, 8, 21, 10, 54, 27) |0        |35          |
new Date(2018, 8, 21, 10, 54, 35) |0        |45          |
```

This assumes that you know your machine names beforehand. If not, you may need to work more on it.

=======================================

Edit: Answer to the comment.

If you want to get the column names dynamically, you can use a dynamic query like this. Create a stored procedure and call to get the data.

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `getUsage`()
BEGIN
    SET @query = NULL;
    SELECT
          GROUP_CONCAT(
          DISTINCT CONCAT('SUM(IF (machineName = "', machineName, '", percentComittedInUse, 0)) AS ', CONCAT(clientName, '_', machineName))
          ) INTO @query
        FROM stsdata.hyperv_perf_memory;

    SET @query = CONCAT('SELECT `date`, ', @query, ' FROM stsdata.hyperv_perf_memory GROUP BY date, clientName');

    PREPARE stmt FROM @query;
    EXECUTE stmt;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
END
```

To get data from this, you can simply execute a query like:

```
call getUsage();
```

Hope it helps!! Feel free to ask if you have any doubts.

Comment: This does help construct the table as I hoped but it doesn't make it readily available if more machine names are added to the database. Do you know of a method where it can run this pivot table for each unique machine name? Thank you

Comment: @kfear please see the edit to my answer. I added a dynamic query.

Comment: I have attempted to create the procedure and at `SET @query = NULL;` we have an error: **Syntax error: missing 'semicolon'.** Also with this query, do I need to change the first line, ie. root@localhost to my Username@MySQLServer and the `Mydb` to the name of my Database ? I am yet to use stored procedures so this is new for me. Thank you very much for your assistance @Nimeshka.

Comment: @kfear yes, they need to be changed accordingly. You can set to it DEFINER=<user-user>@% allow it from any host, or you can completely remove the definer part. It's not mandatory. Just a security restriction. Please see the documentation for more details. Can you elaborate more on that missing semicolon error? How do you create the procedure?

Comment: I managed to get this working and have created the procedure. Thank you! I am now going to work on getting these columns into my chart. The other pieces of this puzzle I need to work out is adding the columns dynamically via PHP

Comment: I've updated the query to handle machines with the same name, we are using machineId. How do we also concat a column called clientName in with the machineName for the column rows? ie. machineName.ClientName


`SELECT`
`GROUP_CONCAT(`
`DISTINCT CONCAT('SUM(IF (machineId = "', machineId, '", `
`percentComittedInUse, 0)) AS ', machineName)`
`) INTO @query`
`FROM stsdata.hyperv_perf_memory;`
`SET @query = CONCAT('SELECT `date`, ', @query, ' FROM `
`stsdata.hyperv_perf_memory GROUP BY date');`
`PREPARE stmt FROM @query;`
`EXECUTE stmt;`
`DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;`

Comment: To clarify on my previous comment we are now hoping for the following columns:
`date` | `machineName.clientName` | `machineName.clientName` | `machineName.clientName` etc... The existing database has these columns already, just not sure how to get the clientName in with the machineName. It looks like using `machineId` is creating the unique ID's to each column however PHP is not handling arrays with the same column name properly so these must be unique prior to bringing these into my charts. Any ideas @NimeshkaSrimal?

Comment: It seems that it does not like passing spaces into @query. If we replace them with an underscore this does work. Is there any way around this?

Comment: @kfear you can concatenate the client name and machine name. Yes, you cannot use spaces in field names. Allowed: any number, a-z, $ or _ (basically  [0-9,a-z,A-Z$_]). To workaround this, you can replace the underscore with a space in your php script. Please see the update to my answer to get the client name along with the machine name. Also, don't keep extending the same question. If you have a new question, please ask a new one.

Comment: @kfear I have updated the procedure. Please see if  it works for you.